# How can I output a Map as jsp:attributes?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a Map containing a String for the key and value.  Basically, I would like to output:

```
<div class="something"
   data-path="path"
   data-linkurl="url"
/>
```

The data-path and data-linkurl are keys in the Map.  Path and url are values.  So, I'd like to output the key and value as:

```
<jsp:attribute name="{key}">{value}</jsp:attribute>
```

The problem is once I add a loop to output the values, I get the error "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: .jsp(65,8) jsp:body must be the subelement of a standard or custom action."

In the code, I have the jsp:body tag.  So, this doesn't work for me:

```
<jsp:element name="div">
  <jsp:attribute name="class">something</jsp:attribute>
    <c:forEach items="myMap">
      <jsp:attribute name="key">value</jsp:attribute>
    </c:forEach>
  <jsp:body></jsp:body>
</jsp:element>
```

I don't even need to use  with MyMap.  It fails just having the loop and static values in jsp:attribute.  Of course, it works if I remove the foreach loop.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try here?

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score -1):

Simple way:

```
<jsp:element name="div">
  <jsp:attribute name="class">something</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:attribute name="data-path">key</jsp:attribute>
  <jsp:attribute name="url">${myMap["key"]}</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

OR ( If you want to write all dynamic attributes )

```
<jsp:element name="div">
  <jsp:attribute name="class">something</jsp:attribute>
  <c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="entry">
     <jsp:attribute name="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</jsp:attribute>
  </c:forEach>
</jsp:element>
```

If you div has body, you can do like this

```
 <jsp:body> ${div_body} </jsp:body>
```

Comment: I wish it were that easy for me.  I had tried that very thing (2nd option you mentioned), but it's throwing the same exception when the forEach loop is in there.  Once I remove it, the page loads fine.  I'm running Tomcat 6.0.37, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do you have jsp:body? If yes.  Add test body content and test

Comment: Yeah, even after adding the <jsp:body> tag, it is working without the foreach.  But, once I add it, it's not longer working.  Out of curiosity, did you test the code that you've posted?  If yes, then it's probably something with my configuration that I need to resolve.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you <jsp:body> have a content inside?

Comment: Yeah, I just basically added some sample text.  Also, the jsp:body error message goes away once the foreach is removed.